# How to prove that $\frac{h-h_1}{h+h_1} +\frac{h-h_2}{h+h_2}+\frac{h-h_3}{h+h_3}+\frac{h-h_4}{h+h_4} \geq 12/5$ for a regular tetrahedron

Tags: geometry

Let $h$ be the height of a regular tetrahedron and let $h_1, h_2, h_3, h_4$ be the distances from a point $P$ to the inside faces of the tetrahedron. Prove that:

$$\frac{h-h_1}{h+h_1} +\frac{h-h_2}{h+h_2}+\frac{h-h_3}{h+h_3}+\frac{h-h_4}{h+h_4} ≥ \frac{12}{5}$$

Is there a simple way?

Comment: Hint: if $h=4$, then the middle point is 1 away from each face; so $\frac{h-h_i}{h+h_i}$ = 3/5 for each $i$.  Prove that if you go away from the middle point, then as one distance decreases, the other three increase; so the sum is always going to be at least 12/5.

Comment: Is $P$ inside the tetrahedron?

Comment: @Kf-Sansoo I don't know, i suppose that P is inside the tetrahedron

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume $P$ is inside the tetrahedron, and let $S$ be the area of the faces of the tetrahedron, then: $\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^4 \dfrac{Sh_i}{3} = V=\dfrac{Sh}{3}\Rightarrow \displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^4 h_i = h$. Put $x_i = \dfrac{h_i}{h} \Rightarrow \displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^4 x_i = 1$, and $LHS = \displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^4 \dfrac{1-x_i}{1+x_i} = \displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^4 f(x_i) \geq 4f\left(\dfrac{\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^4 x_i}{4}\right)= 4f\left(\dfrac{1}{4}\right)= \dfrac{12}{5}$. This is true by convexity of $f(x) = \dfrac{1-x}{1+x}, x \in (0,1)$.

Comment: Note that this method also works if $P$ is not inside the tetrahedron, by assigning proper signs to each $h_i$. In particular, each face of the tetrahedron is contained in a unique plane, which divides $3$-space into two pieces; let the piece containing the interior of the tetrahedron be called positive, and the other piece be called negative. Then, assign $h_i$ a positive or negative sign depending on whether or not $P$ is in the positive or negative half of $3$-space corresponding to face $i$.